# Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I'm trying to do a simple outlook integration with c# using Interop when getting the default folder I always get an error.

I'm using Office 2013 64bit, I only have 9.5 on my RegEdit.

I Followed this  [link](https://crm.superoffice.com/scripts/customer.fcgi?_sf=0&custSessionKey=&customerLang=nl&noCookies=true&action=viewKbEntry&id=113034#2)

Here's my sample code:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder_Contacts;
Outlook.Application outlookObj = application;
Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace1 = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Folder_Contacts = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
```

Once it gets to GetDefaultFolder the error pops out.
[image]

Tried reinstalling,repair, uninstall-install the office but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed, I checked my regedit and saw a bunch of keys with version 9.6, I'm using 9.5.
So what I did is find and replace those 9.6 to 9.5 and checked it every while if one of those fixed the problem. lol. Eventually it did.